# How to add objects to an Array list by alphabetical order of particular variable of object

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I have a library program and within that program is a BorrowBookRecord Record class and a Library class. In the library class contains a 'borrowBook()' method that when called and successfully used, creates a BorrowBookRecord object and adds it to an array list of BorrowBookRecords which is stored in the Library class. My only problem is I have absolutely no idea how to  get the borrowBook() method to store the records in alphabetical order. I wouldn't even know where to start. Each record has a 'student username' as one of its variables which I want to use to as what determines the objects alphabetical order in the list.

This is the borrow book method in the library class

```
 public boolean borrowBook(String librarianUsername, String studentUsername, String bookISBN){
    User user = findUserByUsername(studentUsername);

    if(checkPermissionTypeByUserNameBorrow(librarianUsername) && user.isOverBorrow() && checkPermissionTypeByUserNameReserve(studentUsername)){
        if(checkIfAnyAvaliable(bookISBN)){
              for(Book book: books){
                    if(book.getISBNNumber().equals(bookISBN) && book.checkAvaliable()){
                        book.modifyStatus(BookStatus.Reserved);
                        Date date = new Date();

                        BorrowBookRecord record = new BorrowBookRecord(studentUsername, bookISBN, book.getCopyNumber(), date);
                        borrowRecords.add(record);
     /////>>>this is where record is made.
                        user.increaseNumberOfborrowedBooks();
                        break;
                    }
              }                                   
        }
        else{
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("There are no books of that isbn avaliable to borrow");
            }
    }
    else{
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Student cannot borrow anymore Books/librarian has wrong permissontype");
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a [binary search](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch-java.util.List-T-java.util.Comparator-) with a custom comparator to find the insertion point, as long as you maintain the order:

```
int index = Collections.binarySearch(borrowRecords, record,
        Comparator.comparing(BorrowBookRecord::getStudentUsername));
if (index < 0) {
    index = -(index + 1);
}
borrowRecords.add(index, record);
```

Or you can have `BorrowBookRecord` implement `Comparable` instead of using a comparator.

Comment: Worked like a charm

Comment: The underlying data structure - `Array` will have to shift all the subsequent elements to the right. Wouldn't `LinkedList` do this efficiently?

Comment: @shriyog In theory it might. Practically, ArrayList is almost always more efficient [citation needed]. And LinkedList will slow down the binary search and require pre-insertion traversal.

Comment: @shmosel Thanks for the clarification. I do agree over this.

Answer (score 1):

In cases where the elements must be stored in a sorted manner based on some criteria, one must go of `TreeSet` and not `ArrayList`.

You can replace your data structure to use [Java TreeSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) so that after every insertion you would have your elements ordered as per given criterion.

> The elements are ordered using their natural ordering, or by a
>   Comparator provided at set creation time, depending on which
>   constructor is used.

Here, you need to provide a `Comparator` specific to your ordering requirements. So, to order according to `studentUsername` you must define your Comparator as -

```
public class BookComparator implements Comparator<BorrowBookRecord > {
    @Override
    public int compare(BorrowBookRecord o1, BorrowBookRecord o2) {
        return o1.studentUsername.compareTo(o2.studentUsername);
    }    
}
```

Comment: That will not work unless BorrowBookRecord implements Comparable.

Comment: @tgdavies Correct. Or I can pass a `Comparator` while initializing `TreeSet`.

Comment: Using a set rather than a list imposes a constraint that the BorrowBookRecord items will be unique.

Comment: @JonathanRosenne That's correct. If we want to allow duplicates [TreeMultiset](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/TreeMultiset.html) is an option. What do you think?